# nginx: 502 error: connect() failed (111: Connection refused) with vagrant

Tags: php, magento, ubuntu, nginx, fastcgi

I'm experiencing 502 gateway errors when accessing my site on 127.0.0.1:8000
Working with Vagrant and ubuntu with nginx, trying to install Magento 2.0. After a lot of bugfixxing I still have this 502 error.

Config:

- Ubuntu 14.04 (ubuntu/trusty64 box)
- Php 5.6.18 from ppa
- Nginx 1.8.1

Error log:

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:7777", host: "127.0.0.1:8000", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
```

VagrantFile config: http://pastebin.com/rMSTmwJn

my /etc/php5/pool.d/vagrant.conf (and www.conf) file: http://pastebin.com/hHnFrf55

my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file: http://pastebin.com/0mwR7CxY

which includes this magento nginx config file: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/nginx.conf.sample (no edits)

Also have I edited the user and group in www.conf to 'vagrant'

I'm really stuck on this one. Hope you guys can help! If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: you are working with upstream. But I didn't see upstream config which serves at 127.0.0.1:7777 Could you please type `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 7777` this on your command line which works in vagrant. It will give you active connection on 7777. If there is no result it means you are not serving anyting at.

Comment: @FZE resulting in `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7777          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2036/php-fpm.conf)` (only 1 row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more struggling I found out with  `php5-fpm -t` and `nginx -t` I had an error in my `/etc/php5/pool.d/vagrant.conf` file rule 1 (:1). I change `vagrant` to `[vagrant]`.

Next I got the following error from `php5-fpm -t`: Both www.conf and vagrant.conf serve on port :7777. Makes sense, so I changed www.conf to listen :9000 and everything is working! Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is occur in your nginx config. It only serves your localhost, but you are trying to access from physical, or another virtual machine. Try to add public domain name.
also add `10.0.2.2 public.domain` to client's /etc/hosts file. And change below config's related line as `server_name localhost public.domain;`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost public.domain;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer;

    include /vagrant/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These answers got me close, but weren't my exact problem.

For those interested I'm using Windows 10 with Vagrant - 1.9.3 (laravel/homestead) box.

I was using this in my nginx config:

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

I recently changed it to this:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
```